# Get inserted database value

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

So the with Meteor I insert a value to the database like so:

```
Database.insert({name: 'bob'})
```

However I would like to retrieve the 'bob' value I put in. I am not sure how to retrieve just the bob value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the example shown in the [insert documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#insert), the `insert` will return the `_id` of the inserted document. You can then use it to query the 'name' field using [findOne](http://docs.meteor.com/#findone). As mentioned in the [field-specifier documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers), it is not possible to mix inclusion and exclusion while mentioning the list of fields to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check you are creating a collection

```
    Database = new Meteor.Collection('database');
```

Them the insertion command you use is fine, and you can retrieve that document (record) by name:

```
    persons = Database.find({name:"bob"})
```

To retrieve only one document, use:

```
    person = Database.findOne({name:"bob"})
```

then, you can get the "bob" value using:

```
    name = person.name
```

Comment: It's not correct because in could return not only one document. You should replace it with 'findOne'

Comment: Database.find({name: 'bob'}) returns Localcollection. I just want 'bob'

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
Database.findOne({name:'bob'})
```

or if you use find for multiple results use [fetch](http://docs.meteor.com/#fetch) so the data is given in an array, the above is the same as

```
Database.find({name:"bob"}).fetch()[0]
```

With your code above:

```
inserted_record_id = Database.insert({name: 'bob'})

//getting your document inserted above:
Database.findOne({_id:inserted_record_id})
```